# jQuery UI 1.12 – Activating a tab via link or URL

Tags: jquery-ui

How can I activate a tab based on a hash tag (element ID) in the URL?

I know this question has been asked several times over the years, but the answers are no longer relevant for jQuery 1.10+.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two steps to accomplishing this - first, match up the hash tag (e.g. #SomeValue) to the element ID of the Tab you want active; then second, set said Tab as active.

```
var matchedTab = $('a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]');
$('#tabs').tabs({active:$('#tabs a').index(matchedTab)});
```

The first line is creating a jQ object from the tab element whose `href` attributes matches the hash in the URL. Since the markup of the Tabs plug-in requires ([documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/)) you have an anchor `<a>` element with an `href` attribute, this will find the correct tab (assuming you have one that corresponds to the hash in the URL).

The second line then uses the `active` initialization option to set the desired active tab when initializing the Tabs. The `active` option though requires the zero-based index of that tab within the Tabs collection, so we use the `.index()` jQuery function to get that index & pass it to the `active` option.

Since the sandbox sites all use secured frames, I had to use a dropdown with dummy URLs to "simulate" different how different hash tags work, but it will function just the same using the code above.

CodePen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YvyxvL

You can use the dropdown on that page to simulate the behavior of URLs with different hash tags setting different tabs to active.